# Vertical Spacer in XUL

Tags: xml, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

How do you add vertical spacers in XUL used in Firefox Addons?
(Something similar to HTML `<br />` or `<html:br />` a vertical version of `<spacer flex="1"/>`)

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE overlay SYSTEM "chrome://theaddon/locale/main.dtd">

<vbox xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

  <!-- want some vertical space here -->
  <setting title="&options.changelog.title;" type="control">
    <button label="&options.changelog.label;" 
      oncommand="openDialog('chrome://theaddon/content/changelog.xul', '',
      'dialog=no, modal=no, resizable=yes, width=500, height=600');"/>
  </setting>

</vbox>
```

Comment: `<spacer>` will work if the parent box is a `<vbox>` or container with attribute `align=vertical`.

Comment: I have tried it in `vbox` in inline `options.xul` but doesn't work.. I will add the code to the post

Comment: Ah you're trying to modify the inline options page look? I have lots of practice doing that. Let's chat about it. Do you know how to start chat in this topic? If we can't please email me from my website and let's arrange a time.

Comment: I havent tried the chat.. How is it done for a topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `margin` or `padding` to the `<setting>` as you please, e.g.

```
<setting ... style="margin-top: 2em;">
```

You may also want to play with `border` styles...

PS: Adding dedicated elements such as `<spacer>` would be far more complicated, because you'd need to get the code to insert them in the first place. And the code will [only add `<setting>` elements](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/8bfe3372f848/toolkit/mozapps/extensions/content/extensions.js#l3168).

Comment: Tnx... For some reason I was under the impression that style wouldn't work in XUL (as expected in HTML). That make it a lot easier :)